# how to send input to a daemon in linux

Tags: perl, bash, signals, daemon

```
#!/bin/bash

. /etc/init.d/functions

NAME=foo
DIR=/home/amit/Desktop
EXEC=foo.pl
PID_FILE=/var/run/foo.pid
IEXE=/etc/init.d/foo
RUN_AS=root

if [ ! -f $DIR/$EXEC ]
then
    echo "$DIR/$EXEC not found."
    exit
fi

case "$1" in
start)
    echo -n "Starting $NAME"
cd $DIR
/home/amit/Desktop/foo.pl
    echo "$NAME are now running."
    ;;
stop)
echo -n "Stopping $NAME"
    kill -TERM `cat $PID_FILE`
rm $PID_FILE
    echo "$NAME."
    ;;
force-reload|restart)
    $0 stop
    $0 start
    ;;
  submit)
  echo $2 >> /tmp/jobs
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Use: /etc/init.d/$NAME {start|stop|restart|force-reload}"
    exit 1
  ;;
esac
exit 0
```

i have created a daemon with start and stop options(service foo start/stop) and it works fine. Now I want to send an input to the dameon. something like "service foo submit [argument]" . I want to to know - if user types "service foo submit alexander" , how alexander can be sent to the running daemon ?

Answer (score 0):

If I get the question right - just as you already use positional var $1 you can supply the rest of the arguments to the command as well, i.e.:

"your_start_up_script"  [switch to the script as $1]  [arg 2 will be accessible via $2] [arg 3 will be accessible via $3]
Then inside script you do:

```
    case "$1" in
start)
    echo -n "Starting $NAME"
cd $DIR
/home/amit/Desktop/foo.pl   "$2"  "$3"
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. But I dont want to pass arguments to the scsript when i say service foo start. When i say "service foo start" the script runs as a daemon in a while loop. next when the user says "service foo submit argument" , i need to pass the argument to the running daemon.

Comment: I see, basically you mean 'how do I communicate with a running process via  bash shell' , am I correct ? If so, then indeed the way you start this daemon is not that important...

Comment: yes you are corect. can u suggest me someways that i can communicate with the running daemon and pass arguments after the daemon has started running ? But i want to communitate with the daemon via "service foo submit <argument>"

Comment: - "service" is just a utility (/sbin/service)  that runs any script located in /etc/init.d/ and having corresponding filename. So name your script for passing args "whatever", put it in /etc/init.d/ , then run $service "whatever"  and it will do. BUT the real question is how topass args to daemon here ...  
You don't have bash-way of doing it, so you'd have to provide for it in your daemon, e.g. daemon in a while loop checks for presence of some file and args in it, the file in turn is being created by running aforementioned $service whatever

Comment: submit) 
    echo $2 >> /tmp/job_queue
    ;;                                                                                                        so something like this right ? so when i typpe "service foo submit job" , "job" gets written to a file located somewhere which is continuously monitored for input by daemon running in a while loop. check the edited code for the submit part.

Comment: yes, exactly. Actually, for completeness sake, there is a way to communicate with a running process - via signal, you'd register a trap for user-defined signal inside your script and then once you issue (through some script wrapper) such signal, the daemon can act on it. Only that it seems to me not well-suited for passing args .

Comment: Yes youa re absolutely correct and a rockstart! thanks for the help